# long options and short options in getopt python

Tags: python, getopt

In the below code I am mixing both short and long options. Also notice that "--longoption1" is separated by "=" and "--longoption2" is separated by space. But getopt does not differentiate between space and = for long options. On the contrary for short options anything followed by the short option (x,y,z) is considered as the value for the option. Notice "-x:shortvalue1 -y shortvalue2 -zshortvalue3" x is separated by :, y by space and z is not even separated by anything, but still getopt parses as I can imagine.

```
import sys, getopt

commandoptions = "--longoption1=longvalue1 --longoption2 longvalue2 -x:shortvalue1 -y shortvalue2 -zshortvalue3"
parsedoptions = commandoptions.split()
print("Split by space ", parsedoptions)

opts, additionalArgs = getopt.getopt(parsedoptions, "x:y:z:", ["longoption1=", "longoption2="])
print("options ", opts)
```

In continuation, why does the following code fail? Notice that "--longoption3longvalue3" is similar to "-zshortvalue3". I mean the option and its value are not separated. In this case short options still work but long options do not. Instead it causes the following error:

> `GetoptError: option --longoption3longvalue3 not recognized`

I was following https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html but I could not find any references for the answer I am looking for.

```
import sys, getopt

commandoptions = "--longoption1=longvalue1 --longoption2 longvalue2 --longoption3longvalue3 -x:shortvalue1 -y shortvalue2 -zshortvalue3"
parsedoptions = commandoptions.split()
print("Split by space ", parsedoptions)

opts, additionalArgs = getopt.getopt(parsedoptions, "x:y:z:", ["longoption1=", "longoption2=", "longoption3="])
print("options ", opts)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not compiling"? What kind of error output do you see?

Comment: I get this error "GetoptError: option --longoption3longvalue3 not recognized"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct, intended behaviour following both [BSD](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/FreeBSD/getopt_long.3.html) and [GNU](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long) `getopt_long(3)` conventions. (Notice that the "long option" idea originated from GNU and is not part of the POSIX API).

From the GNU man page:

> A long option may take a parameter, of the form `--arg=param` or `--arg param`.

To pass a long option to the program, the name of the option and the value must be joined by either an equal sign `=`, or separated as neighbouring items in `argv`, i.e.

```
--longoption3 longvalue3
```

Joining them together will cause the underlying `getopt_long` library function to recognize this part as one long option whose name is `longoption3longvalue3`, which is correctly unrecognized.

Comment: Thanks. I think this part " the value must be joined by either an equal sign =, or separated as neighbouring items in argv" was the key.